# Magento - Change CSS for Product & Category Grid/List depending on category ID

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I would like to find a way to change the CSS of a product depending on the category it is in.

For example:

Valentines (ID31)
Mothers Day (ID32)

Some of the products may be in other categories also, If the product is in a standard category than the CSS should not change and remain in the standard format. The css should only change for the products assigned to the above categorie OR sub categorie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you will get in core Magento is to create a custom theme and apply it to a category. Ensure that `Apply To Products` is set to `Yes` and that it's child categories have `Use Parent Category Settings` set to `Yes`. When viewing the product directly from the category it should then have the theme.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for your help Peter.